# NodeJS For Loop Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise

I am trying to write a code as follows -

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var a = 0;
for( var i in myArr) {
  rp('someURL?q='+myArr[i])
  .then(function (response) {
      myArr[i] = response;
  });
}
return myArr;
```

How can I wait for each request then proceed the for loop for next iteration and in the end return myArr?

Comment: You're getting the same request?

Comment: You really should look at using Promise.all(). As @NoobTW mentioned though, you are calling the same request on each iteration and storing the same result in each array index. Does the request change in some other manner between calls or does the response change on the server at random?

Comment: Yep, I can give you an example with Promise.all if you're calling different requests.

Comment: In any case though, you will always be returning a promise, never a array.

Comment: I have updated the question body. Can't use Promise.all as it needs to be run in serial. An example will be nice. Thanks everyone

Comment: Why would you need to wait for each request to be processed? It doesn't look like a subsequent request relies on a previous request. You could process them all at the same time.

Comment: Actually actual code is quite big. So this is just a skeleton and the final response does depend on every subsequent request.

Answer (score -1):

If you can send request all at the same time, you can use `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all(myArr.map(function(q){ return rp('someURL?q='+q); })
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        // here's all the requests.
    });
```

Comment: You're creating a new Promise when you don't need one - `getRequest` could just as easily return `rp('someURL?q='+q)`

Comment: @Adam Oops, you're right.

Comment: Actually actual code is quite big. So this is just a skeleton and the final response does depend on every subsequent request.

Comment: @AbhigyanSingh then you should use `reduce`